# Android AnimationDrawable scaling

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that initially has a Bitmap Image:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

By default that imageview scales the bitmap to fill the width that is what I want.

But the problem is that when I change the source of the ImageView to an AnimationDrawable, that is build by several images of the same size of the original, then animation isn't scaled at all and returns to the original.

How can I do that scale the animation drawable in the same way that is scaled the bitmap?

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with this programmatically by using ImageView setPadding(). I calculated the difference between the ImageView height and width and what I wanted to display and set my own padding so that the usable size of the ImageView exactly matched my animation.

It's brute force and not very flexible but I've not seen any better solution posted and this issue has come up many times.